# Sequential Looping and changing list

Tags: loops, rust, foreach, iterator

I have a 2D list of structs that must be sequentially passed into a series of loops. Each loop will change the function in a way that affects the output from the following loop. All elements must have completed the first loop before the second loop can be started.

Currently, I have a system that looks like this:

```
self.list.iter().flatten().for_each(|e| { e.funcOne() });
self.list.iter().flatten().for_each(|e| { e.funcTwo() });
.....
```

While this does work, it is not elegant - it also requires the 2d list to be repeatedly flattened. One solution could be to store the `self.list.iter().flatten()` into its own variable, however, this would require the cloning of said variable each time I wanted to loop through it.

My Ideal solution would include something syntactically similar to this:

```
self.list.iter().flatten().for_each(|e| e.funcOne()).for_each(|e| e.funcTwo()) ....... ;
```

Comment: Should be easy to make a function that accepts a closure and does the iterator part.

Comment: Cloning the iterator is not the same as cloning the list and is very cheap. Creating the iterator from scratch is also very cheap (same amount of cheapness) - and `flatten()` is not really expensive (it does not allocate or something). Even though you can create a function that will allow you to use the version you want (return a clone of the iterator from `for_each()`), it'll not be cheaper. The only way is to collect the flatten version, but it is likely to be _much_ costlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance-wise flattening is fine as @Chayim Friedman mentioned.
If you take a look at the [flatten() source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/flatten.rs.html#291), it is not really converting the 2D-array into 1D-array. What it does is it lazily iterates over one row via a row iterator, and when the row exhausts, it switches to iterate over the next row iterator, and so on until there's no next row.

If you want a functional (one line) solution, consider this:

```
let functions = [
    ElemType::funcOne,
    ElemType::funcTwo,
];

functions.iter().for_each(|f| self.list.iter().flatten().for_each(f));
```